Her husband and mother-in-law talk to each other in French so she WON'T/CAN'T/DOESN'T understand
On a TV show about the problems that a couple and a mother-in-law go through, the presenter says:

Amanda says that she can't stand it when her husband and mother-in-law talk to each other in French so she won't understand.

I would expect the second part of the sentence something like this: "....so she can't/doesn't understand...", because as far as I know "...won't undertand..." is for situations when a problem happens repeatedly. For example,

I have explained it to her many times, but she won't understand.

(won't is fine here, because her failing to understand has happened many times.)
So, what might be the reason the TV presenter used "...won't understand.." when they already don't want her to understand.

That's 100% idiomatic American English.  I think BrE as well.  will not  (contracted won't) expresses their (perceived) intention.  This is indeed a repeated thing with them, according to the wife.  But it need not be.  When  you place an order for these illegal munitions, use an encrypted chat program so the authorities won't be able to track us.  There it's future aspect.   I think you have in mind the "headstrong" meaning: I keep telling her to move over a few inches but she won't take my advice and throws gutter ball after gutter ball.

It implies that they are doing it on purpose (so that she won't be able to understand). In your example, she won't understand means that she refuses to, not that she does it repeatedly (although that information is given by the first part of the sentence).

Generally, if we describe some action in the present and identify the intended purpose or consequence, said purpose is in the future.

Put on your coat so you won't be cold.

This applies even when the present is used to refer to a regularly recurring action, as in the example you found.
Note that a similar time shift occurs for the past:

They used to speak to each other in Bengali so she wouldn't understand.

